# Flink 1.6.0 job jar upload size limit

Tags: apache-flink

What's job jar file size limit and is there a chance I could override it ?

With Flink 1.6.0 out and with a fully RESTified [job submission](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/monitoring/rest_api.html#submitting-programs) I tried uploading jar like:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8081/jars/upload -X POST -F "jarfile=@word-count-beam/target/word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar" --verbose
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8081 (#0)
> POST /jars/upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 108716165
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------ab44aa4cd2db3c75
> 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
< content-length: 0
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

but I get:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Actual jar file size is:

```
$ du -h word-count-beam/target/word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar
113M    word-count-beam/target/word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar
```

I'm running Flink in docker using `1.6.0-scala_2.11` image.

UPDATE: it's same when trying uploading from Web UI:
[image: flink jar upload WebUI screenshot]

NOTE: jar upload feature worked with Flink 1.5 (Docker).

Comment: Are you sure that the jar file you are trying to upload isn't in use by any other process? Depending on your OS that might cause a problem while uploading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@robosoul , I think there is a [rest limit in config](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/config.html#rest-client-max-content-length), by default the max size is 104857600 in bytes, looks like you are exceeding the limit

Comment: thanks fro the answer. Setting 'rest.server.max-content-length' solved it.